# Laravel validation does not work with many fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I have a strange Laravel behaviour. If I validate my form with less than about 10 fields, everything works perfectly fine, including showing error messages (e.g. "field1 is required"):

```
public function myFctName(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'year' => 'required',
            'field1' => 'required',
            'field2' => 'required'
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return back()->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput();
    }

    return view('companiesView');
}
```

My form has 23 fields. As soon as I add around 10 fields, everythings works fine if there are no validation errors. Here is the second examplecode:

```
public function myFctName(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'year' => 'required',
            'field1' => 'required',
            'field2' => 'required',
            'field3' => 'required',
            'field4' => 'required',
            'field5' => 'required',
            'field6' => 'required',
            'field7' => 'required',
            'field8' => 'required',
            'field9' => 'required',
            'field10' => 'required',
            'field11' => 'required',
            'field12' => 'required',
            'field13' => 'required',
            'field14' => 'required'
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return back()->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput();
    }

    return view('companiesView');
}
```

If there is an validation error, the redirect (back()) still works. However, there is no error message displayed.

If I change the line `return back()->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput();` to `return back()->withErrors($validator->errors());`, the error messages are displayed. So the problem must be with the `withInput()` function.

Moreover, with the `withInput()` part in place, there is a warning in the Chrome console (not happening in Firefox though): `Set Cookie header is ignored in response from url: ... Cookie length should be less than or equal to 4096 characters`. I am not actively doing anything with Cookies at this point.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Clear your browser cookie first.

Comment: @SharifMohammadEunus done; Unfortunately, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`withInput()` is using cookie/session under the hood to store the old values. Maybe those are flooding.

An alternate could be

```
$request->validate([
  'year' => 'required',
]);
```

```
<input type="text" name="year" value="{{old('year')}}">
```

for displaying the errors

```
@if($errors->any())

 @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
   {{$error}}
 @endforeach


@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried the `$request->validate()`-stuff - unfortunately, I still receive the same error. The form contains 23 text-inputs (no image etc), the names for these are between 4 and 20 characters - so nothing really special here. Laravel should be able to handle this kind of data volume, right?

Comment: Yes. Give me your form and controller. I want to give it a try.

Comment: I've uploaded both files (in the most simplest version): http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=82013323074319045773 Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the session driver. It is probably set to cookie which can only store 4096 characters. Set it to file, database, or redis.

In .env

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
```

to

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
```